# Find the Nucleus and Image of the following linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the Nucleus and Image of the following linear transformation:

$f\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ = $(a+b-c, a+2c+d, 2a+b+c+d)$

a) Core and Image subspace
b) Core and Image base.

I'm given a question like this but I have no idea that what Nucleus, Core can possibly mean. Anyone have any idea about the terms?

Comment: It probably means the kernel of the transformation, i.e. all matrices which are mapped to 0 by $f$.

Comment: Okay, but then nucleus and core  both mean kernel?

Comment: Also it's said to find image base. Generally we find basis, not base. What do think, it's a typo?

Comment: The answer to both your questions is: probably yes. You could look for other questions from the same source to confirm your suspicion.

Comment: Another phrase for it is "nullspace".